Maximum of $M$ random variables which are the maximum of $m$ normal distributed variables.
Let $X_{i,1}, \dots, X_{i, m}$ be a collection of normally distributed random variables $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and let $X_{i, (m)} = \max_{j\leq m}X_{i, j}$. I know from extreme value theory that $X_{i, m}$ approaches $\sqrt{2\log m}$ asymptotically, in particular it can be shown that
$$\text{Pr}\bigg[\sqrt{2\log m}\sqrt{1-\frac{\log\log m}{\log m}}\leq X_{i,(m)}\leq \sqrt{2\log m}\bigg]\geq 1-O\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log m}}\bigg) \qquad (1).$$
Now consider $M$ collections of $m$ normal random variables, I'd like to find whether this assertion is true for any $M>0$
$$\text{Pr}[\max_{i\leq M}X_{i, (m)}\geq \sqrt{2\log{m}}]\leq o(1) \qquad (2),$$
where $o(1)$ is any function going to zero for $m\to \infty$.
It seems to me intuitive this property, as any extreme $X_{i,m}$ is $\sqrt{2\log m}$ asymptotically, but I cannot find a good argument.
A simple union bound on $(1)$ is not sufficient as I'll get an upper bound in the probability $O(M/\sqrt{\log m})$ (so we would need $M = o(\sqrt{\log m})$). Another approach is using the asymptotic distribution of the extreme of $m$ Gaussian random variable, which is a Gumbel distribution with mean $\mu + \beta \gamma$ where $\mu \sim \sqrt{2\log m}$, $\beta \sim (\sqrt{2\log m})^{-1}$ and $\gamma$ a constant. Then, the maximum of $M$ random variables Gumbel distributed is still Gumbel distributed with mean $\mu + \beta \log(M) +\beta \gamma$. The factor $\beta\log M$ is an $o(1)$ if $\frac{\log M}{\sqrt{\log m}}=o(1)$, hence for $M = o(e^{\sqrt{\log m}})$, while for bigger $M$ the expectation of the maximum gets an asymptotical additive factor making $(2)$ not true.
I'd like to prove $(2)$ at least for $M=O(m)$. I appreciate any reference for this problem, also in the situation where $X_{i, (m)}$ and $X_{j, (m)}$ are correlated.
Thanks.

Is it not equivalent to finding maximum of $m\times M$ normal random variables?

It seems equivalent yes, but if it is then $\max_{i \leq M} X_{i, (m)}$ would converge to $\sqrt{2\log(M\cdot m)}$, which is in contrast with the union bound argument.

I don't see how it contradicts the union bound argument. The union bound will usually result in a looser bound.
